# How to Interpret and Address Non-Gaussian Measurement Post-Fit Residuals of a Kalman Filter?

Tags: residuals, kalman-filter

I'm using a Kalman filter, optimized via hyperparameter search for both the feature matrix (about 300 variables post my most recent hyperparameter grid search), a ridge regression-based observation model, and a shrinkage estimator for the noise covariance matrix. Despite a (seemingly) adequate fit, my post-fit measurement residuals ($y_{k|k} = z_k - \mathbf{H}_k \hat{x}_{k|k}$) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Update) show non-Gaussian distributions, as evidenced by graphs and statistical tests.

Does this suggest my model is sub-optimal, potentially due to mis-specification, missed non-linearities, inaccurate noise covariance estimates, or outliers?

To improve model accuracy, I'm considering: a) enhancing the feature matrix to better capture dependencies, b) exploring extended Kalman filters for non-linear state-measurement relationships, and c) improving estimation methods for process and measurement noise covariance matrices.

I have included residual plots below. My measurements include three channels and my feature matrix consists of three hundred variables:

[image: Residual qqplots]

[image: Residual histograms]